# launch file to run nodes on multiple machines

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a lunch file to run a node on my turtlebot robot and visualizes the results in rviz on my workstation. To start the turtlebot I like to include the minimal.launch file which is located on the turtlebot.
The launch file I am writing is on the workstation.
Can someone help me to configure the "include    " statement to let the launch file know that minimal.launch is located on the turtlebot. the "include" command doesnot have "machine=..." option.

What does this mean "You can also use the $(env ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE) syntax within include tags to load in .launch files based on environment variables (e.g. MACHINE_NAME)."

Also, do you have a launch file to do what is state in : Talker / listener across two machines
[www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72733/launch-file-to-run-nodes-on-multiple-machines/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to look at the section 4 of this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)

---

Originally posted by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) with karma: 90 on 2013-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0